# c++ convert memory into data structure

Tags: c++, memory, data-structures, reverse-engineering

When debugging an application I have found in memory a structure that I am 100% certain only consists of 4 strings. Though I am not quite sure how I would convert it to a data structure so I can use the structures pointer address to access values. For example here is what the data struct looks like in memory (as an example lets say it is CONSISTENTLY located at the memory address 0x123456) [image]

The data structureconsists of 4 separate strings

```
string 1 = ad
string 2 = dgdhkkkkkkhkk
string 3 = ggghhjk
string 4 = dgcfoh
```

And I have tried creating a data struct like

```
struct reversedConnectionDat_t
{
    char * data1;
    char * data2;
    char * data3;
    char * data4;
}
```

and this is how I tried accessing the data

```
reversedConnectionDat_t * storeDat = (reversedConnectionDat_t*)0x123456;
print(storeDat->data3);
```

But it does not seem to work. Am I not reading the strings from memory properly?

(Oh and the strings will sometimes change from what I posted in the example code posted above, i.e sometimes string 1 will be 7 in length and string 3 will only be 2 in length etc...)

Comment: The memory does not contain pointers, so your struct shouldn't either. Use plain char arrays. And disable padding and alignment...

Comment: They don't look like strings to me, how are you sure that's what they are?

Comment: @harold I know the function they are being passed to. The function takes 4 parameters, and all 4 are strings.

Answer (score 2):

You have a pointer to a structure of pointers so even if you point the structure to the correct memory address, you still have uninitialized pointers inside the structure. You need to provide them with actual memory. I would try setting up your structure like this ...

```
struct reversedConnectionDat_t
{
    char data1 [3];
    char data2 [50];
    char data3 [50];
    char data4 [50];
}
```

BTW, I didn't count the spaces. I just kind of guessed at it but you get the idea.

Comment: The problem is that the strings are not a consistent size. I.e. they will sometimes change so they are not always what I have put in the example code above

Comment: @reflexdev: You make the char arrays the *maximum size* that the strings can be. For example, if your first string is always one or two characters, plus the null terminator, you'd make the first array length 3, as shown in the answer. It looks like the data is several maximum-length buffers with 0-terminated strings. If that's the case, then this answer is the correct one (provided you give the correct buffer sizes for `data2`, `data3`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I think you've mis-identified that data structure. I suspect that what you have is three independent buffers, each of which can hold one or more null-terminated strings.

The first structure is 68 bytes long and contains `"ad\0dgdhkkkkkkhkk\0"` (followed by enough `\0` to fill the buffer.

It's possible that this buffer is really only 64 bytes long, and that the four bytes after it are used for some other data element.

The second buffer looks to be 64 bytes long, containing a single string and padded with `\0` characters to fill out the 64 bytes.

It's impossible to say how long the third buffer is. All we know is that it's long enough to hold the string `"dgcfoh\0"`. I'd *guess* that the buffer is 64 bytes long, but be willing to revise that opinion if I get more data.

I think the structure you want is:

```
struct s
{
    char data1[68]; // buffer holds one or more null-terminated strings
    char data2[64];
    char data3[64].
}
```

Based on the scant information you've given us, that's what I'd start with. Then you need a way to parse a buffer of null-terminated strings. That is, get the two individual strings from the first buffer. That's a pretty easy bit of C code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using pointers(`char*`) and the structure size of your structure is the size of the 4 pointers. If you want to get the strings you should use arrays(`char[]`) with fixed size.

This will only work if your string size are equal to the buffer size.

IMO the best way is to get the in a char array then find the null terminators
`/0` and then configure your pointers to point to the start of each string(at the start and right after the first 3 null terminators).

```
char* pointerToMem = something; //your strings data
yourStruct.str1 = pointerToMem;
while(*pointerToMem != '\0')
{
    pointerToMem++;
}
yourStruct.str2 = pointerToMem + 1;
```

This is how you can make the struct of pointers work. This code is not optimal and you should not use it as it but it shows how can you get the strings from the memory. To have a C string you only need the address of the first character and some null terminator at the end.

Comment: there's a typo, you have written null character as `'/0'` whereas it should be '`\0'`

Comment: *This will only work if your string size are equal to the buffer size.* That's incorrect. The strings are 0-terminated, so as long as the string length doesn't exceed the buffer size, the `char[]` will work.

Comment: @JimMischel Incorrect. If you allocate buffers with fixed size you must pray that the strings that will come will exactly match the allocated buffers.
If that is not true the data from the strings will fill the buffers sequentially till there is no more space. So if you strbuffer1(`char[]`) is 50 bytes you may fit all of the strings there and when you try to read them you'll get only the first. The next 3 buffers will be filled with garbage

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand what's wrong with your code except for your `magicnumber:0x123456`, casting which might not suit your structure. Are you sure your `magic-number` results in data compatible to the struct defined by you? Like, if you'll try to access `storeDat->data3`, it'll definitely be leading to seg-fault except you do something as follows or you are very lucky.

```
struct R{
    char *a;
    char *b;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct R *r1 = (struct R*) malloc(sizeof(struct R));
    r1->a = "12333";      //Pointing to a string literal
    r1->b = "12331";      //Pointing to a string literal

    int address = (int)&r1;
    struct R *r2 = (struct R*) address;
    std::cout<<r2->b;
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. - I'm not a good programmer. But was just curious to answer, as I thought it might be of some help. Sorry, if I couldn't understand your problem properly.